# Sufficiency of the condition for this linear programming problem to have solutions.

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming

I'm looking for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ which satisfy the following constraints:

$$
\begin{align*}
&x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0\\
&x_1+x_2\geq a\\
&x_2+x_3\geq b\\
&x_3+x_1\geq c\\
&x_1+x_2+x_3=1
\end{align*}
$$

where $a,b,c\geq 0$.

It is easy to find a necessary condition:
$$
\begin{align*}
&a+b+c\leq2\\
&0\le a,b,c\leq1
\end{align*}
$$

I was told that it is also a sufficient condition. However, I cannot prove it. Can anyone help me?